# How can I "alternate" display the content of two lists?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Im trying to achieve being able to display the content of two lists displayed in the following way or at least something similar to the following:

```
list_1 = [price1, price2, price3, price_n]

list_2 = [concept1, concept2, concept3, concept_n]
```

And when printed I want to display that info like this:

```
price1

concept1

price2 

concept2
```

(you get the idea)

Im using a a "for" loop, however,  im not sure how to include the second list for it to be displayed like that on the same "for" or how can achieve this?

Thanks for any feedback provided.

Comment: So, what should happen when the two lists' length isn't the same??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the function `zip` is specifically made for this - iterate through two sequences side-by-side:

```
for price, concept in zip(list_1, list_2):
    print(price)
    print(concept)
```

Comment: It worked like a charm, I appreciate it I was not aware this was a thing. I will understand the concept as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
list_1 = ['price1', 'price2', 'price3', 'price_n']

list_2 = ['concept1', 'concept2', 'concept3', 'concept_n']

for i in range(len(list_2)):
    print(list_1[i],list_2[i])
```

Are you looking for this?